# Using VBA. How to restrict objects in MS PowerPoint to overlap with each other?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Using VBA from excel to handle PowerPoint. 
 If 1st Textbox gets bigger, and starts to overlap with another Textbox it MUST to push 2nd TextBox out of 1st TextBox.

[image]

Comment: If you post the code you currently have, you will get far better help.